# Xamarin Mac Screen Unreadable

Tags: macos, xamarin

After the last Xamarin update on my Mac, the screen is no longer readable. It thinks I'm in India, but I'm in Arizona. When I click report a bug, it goes to xamarin.in before redirecting to the main site.

How can I resolve this issue? I can't find anything on the Xamarin site to help. Thanks.

[Xamarin screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTtXe.png)

Answer (score 0):

This should be fixed, but if you encounter it again, clearing the font cache will help:

http://osxdaily.com/2015/01/08/clear-font-caches-databases-mac-os-x/